# iPhone - Different Default Boolean Value on Device

Tags: iphone, objective-c, boolean

I've recently had a bit of code work perfectly on the simulator, and screw up on device. Why? - It's very simple, but I can't explain the explantion.

I did a little testing, by creating a new view-based app, added a label and an outlet for the label, and wrote this code in the viewDidLoad:

```
BOOL b;
if (b) {
    label.text = @"Value = YES";
}
else {
    label.text = @"Value = NO";
}
```

Interestingly enough, here are the results:

> iOS Simulator (4.2): Value = NO
>  iOS Simulator (4.3): Value = NO
> iPod Touch 2G (4.2.1) Value = YES
> iPhone 3G (4.2.1) Value = YES

What does this suggest? - Well to me it looks like that on devices, the default boolean value is YES, and on the simulator, the default boolean value is NO.

Can anyone clarify if this is the case? Also if someone could explain that behavior I would be very interested.

I am **not** interested in solutions to the problem, clearly it can be solved by setting the desired default (in my case `NO`) manually.

Thanks.

Comment: wow thats pretty interesting, thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Objective-C is just a superset of C, and in C declaring a variable like this just gives it memory on the stack. The variable isn't set to anything when it is declared, so whatever was last on the stack is now in your variable `b`.

In short, it's undefined, and will vary from implementation to implementation. That's what the spec says.

Comment: however this behaviour is really consistent... I've repeated this numerous times and it happens in multiple applciations

Comment: I suspect that on OS X, an application's memory is zeroed out before use, for security reasons (so one process can't snoop around reading another's memory once it's closed).

Comment: However, on iOS, you're much more likely to see YES, since a BOOL is actually an 8-bit value, and `if` considers anything non-zero to be YES.

Comment: @Alex Coplan That a behavior is consistent neither means that it is more than coincidence nor can or should be relied on. No one should program by coincidence.

Comment: Not really. Minor change elsewhere could make it change. Or the 1001st time you run it. Or if you run it at midnight. Or if running in landscape. Who knows, it is undefined. Why do you care at all BTW?

Comment: When coding in C, never - ever - use a variable before initializing it.

Comment: Just to clarify - I didn't actually write this code - I was debugging my team member's code and was interested as to why this happened that's all

Answer (score 4):

Undefined behavior is undefined.